# Linkedin API get profile picture organization

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to get the authenticated user, organizations with profile picture like this:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee&projection=(elements*(organizationalTarget~(localizedName,profilePicture)))
```

But I get this back:

> {"elements":[{"organizationalTarget!":{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"not
> enough permissions to access field profilePicture for GET
> /organizationsLookup","status":403},"organizationalTarget":"urn:li:organization:93086400"},{"organizationalTarget!":{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"not
> enough permissions to access field profilePicture for GET
> /organizationsLookup","status":403},"organizationalTarget":"urn:li:organization:73873422"}]}

Why is this the case? All scopes the user has:

```
r_liteprofile
w_member_social
r_emailaddress
rw_organization_admin
r_organization_admin
r_organization_social
```

When I try this (with no `profilePicture`), it's working:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee&projection=(elements*(organizationalTarget~(localizedName)))
```

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before you use the tags. The API tag starts with: _"DO NOT USE."_

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Don't tag your questions with the tag `api` and read the tag descriptions before you tag your questions with a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed need to be this:

[https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee&projection=(elements*(organizationalTarget~(localizedName,logoV2(original~:playableStreams))))](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee&projection=(elements*(organizationalTarget%7E(localizedName,logoV2(original%7E:playableStreams)))))